# Use numpy masked array on an array of arrays without getting a flattened output

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Consider the following code

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], ['NaN', 4, 'NaN'], [7, 8, 9]])

# Convert 'NaN' strings to masked values
mask = np.ma.masked_where(x == 'NaN', x)

# Get a boolean array indicating where the original array is not masked
bool_arr = ~mask.Mask

# Filter the original array using the boolean array
filtered_arr = x[bool_arr]

print(filtered_arr)
```

The code above results in the following output

```
['1' '2' '3' '4' '7' '8' '9']
```

However I want my output to look as follows

```
[['1' '2' '3'],
 ['4'],
 ['7' '8' '9']]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You want your integers converted to strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an array of strings:

```
In [22]: x
Out[22]: 
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['NaN', '4', 'NaN'],
       ['7', '8', '9']], dtype='<U11')
```

and a masked array with the same strings:

```
In [23]: masked
Out[23]: 
masked_array(
  data=[['1', '2', '3'],
        [--, '4', --],
        ['7', '8', '9']],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value='N/A',
  dtype='<U11')
```

Masked arrays have a method for returning the values:

```
In [24]: masked.compressed()
Out[24]: array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '8', '9'], dtype='<U11')

In [25]: masked.compressed?
Signature: masked.compressed()
Docstring:
Return all the non-masked data as a 1-D array.
```

All indexing with a boolean array returns a 1d array.  It can't return a 2d array like the original, since in general each row may have a different number of elements.  Specifically in your case you want a list with 3,1,3 sized elements.  `numpy` whole array methods don't produce that kind of thing.

To get 1d arrays by row, you have to work row by row:

```
In [30]: [row[row!='NaN'] for row in x]
Out[30]: 
[array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U11'),
 array(['4'], dtype='<U11'),
 array(['7', '8', '9'], dtype='<U11')]
```

Or may be you want to remove the 'nan' by column:

```
In [32]: [row[row!='NaN'] for row in x.T]
Out[32]: 
[array(['1', '7'], dtype='<U11'),
 array(['2', '4', '8'], dtype='<U11'),
 array(['3', '9'], dtype='<U11')]
```

Probably not, but do you see the inherent ambiguity in your quest?

If you cast the array to float:

```
In [34]: x = x.astype(float)
In [35]: x
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [nan,  4., nan],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

and can mask with:

```
In [36]: np.ma.masked_invalid(x)
Out[36]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        [--, 4.0, --],
        [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

You still have flattening issue when it comes to extracting the non-masked values.

```
In [40]: np.ma.masked_invalid(x).compressed()
Out[40]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 7., 8., 9.])
```

But there are a number of functions that let you work with the non-nan values of an array, such as taking the row-wise mean:

```
In [42]: np.nanmean(x,axis=1)
Out[42]: array([2., 4., 8.])
```

The list of lists (or arrays) that you desire looses most of the computational advantages that you normally get with a 2d array.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I was trying to see if it would be possible to remove the `nans` without having to use a loop but I guess there's no way around that.

Comment: that really depends on what you need to do after removing the nans.  Once you have that list of varying length rows, you are stuck with using loops on those rows.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the code is that it’s flattening the array when you index it with a boolean array. Instead of using a boolean array to index the original array, you can use a list comprehension to create a new list of lists where each inner list contains the non-masked elements from the corresponding row of the original array

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], ['NaN', 4, 'NaN'], [7, 8, 9]])

mask = np.ma.masked_where(x == 'NaN', x)

filtered_arr = [row[row != 'NaN'].tolist() for row in x]

print(filtered_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is not a valid numpy array, it should be a multiple of all dimensions.

When you run `x[bool_arr]`, numpy internally flattens the array. This enable you to assign any input as it will also be flattened:

```
x[bool_arr] = list('ABCDEFG')

array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['NaN', 'D', 'NaN'],
       ['E', 'F', 'G']], dtype='<U21')
```

You might want to fall back to python lists:

```
filtered_arr = [d[~m].tolist() for d,m in zip(mask.data, mask.mask)]
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```